# Laravel Feature test "ActingAs" is not actually query the DB for the user

Tags: laravel

In Feature Test, when using the `actingAs`, the user is not really populated from the DB. Therefore, the test is not perfectly reflecting what's really happened when making http request.
Lets say that I have this test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Api;

use App\Models\Agent;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Tests\TestCase;

class MeTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testMe()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $agent = factory(Agent::class)->create();
        $agent->users()->save($agent);

        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/api/me');

        $response->assertJsonStructure(['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']);
        $response->assertJsonStructure(['agent' => ['name', 'agency_title']]);

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

In the `User` model I have `protected $appends = ['agent'];`. 
The test failed and complains that the `agent` is not there, therefore, requesting the same endpoint using real http request giving me the agent as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Why not instead of doing this

```php
 $response->assertJsonStructure(['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']);
 $response->assertJsonStructure(['agent' => ['name', 'agency_title']]);
```

do this instead

```php
$response->assertJsonStructure([
    'first_name', 
    'last_name', 
    'email',
    'agent' => ['name', 'agency_title']
]);
```